# how to remove comma from data in scrapy?

Tags: python, string, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get a clean output because When I scrape the website it gives, reviewed so I am trying to strip it so it only shows **6ft 6in**.

```
  def parse_player(self, response):
        Player_Height = response.css('.nba-player-vital_top-left p:nt-child(2):not(span) ::text').extract()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLwRX.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What is the value of `Player_Height` and what do you want it to be insead?

Comment: I'm guessing Player_Height is a list in which case, try this: str = ''.join(Player_Height) .  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: how to get in this format???